# How to dispose DisposeBag when using ViewModelOwners with ReactiveCocoa

Tags: reactive-cocoa, reactive-swift

[ViewModelOwners](https://github.com/krzysztofzablocki/ViewModelOwners) documents how to use with ReactiveCocoa `CompositeDisposable`

The [Example](https://github.com/krzysztofzablocki/ViewModelOwners/blob/master/Examples/ReactiveSwift/ViewModelOwners/ViewController.swift) is even implemented with ReactiveCocoa.

However, I do not understand how the `disposeBag` is actually disposed since `CompositeDisposable` does not dispose automatically on `deinit`

I'm trying the example and add a log message to the disposable:

```swift
func didSetViewModel(_: ViewModel, disposeBag: CompositeDisposable) {
  disposeBag += AnyDisposable {
    print("Disposed Profile")
  }
}
```

The message is never printed when the controller is deallocated.

I would think that you would need to dispose the bag manually on `deinit`, but the associated object is not exposed, so I can not get the `disposeBag` in `deinit`.

The best thing I came up with that works is using `lifetime` from ReactiveCocoa like this:

```swift
func didSetViewModel(_: ViewModel, disposeBag: CompositeDisposable) {
  disposeBag += AnyDisposable {
    print("Disposed Profile")
  }

  self.reactive.lifetime.observeEnded {
    if !disposeBag.isDisposed {
      disposeBag.dispose()
    }
  }
}
```

But this seems problematic, e.g. if this is a `ReusableViewModelOwner`, then all **but** the last disposeBags have already been disposed but I'm still retaining them...

So basically, my question is: How are you supposed use `ViewModelOwners` with `ReactiveCocoa.CompositeDisposable`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the question, `ReactiveSwift.CompositeDisposable` does not automatically dispose on deinit.

But ReactiveSwift already has a solution for this: `ScopedDisposable` which does exactly that.

So the solution to the original question is, to use `ScopedDisposable<CompositeDisposable>` instead of plain `CompositeDisposable`:

```swift
extension ScopedDisposable: ViewModelOwnerDisposeBagProtocol where Inner == CompositeDisposable {
    public convenience init() {
        self.init(CompositeDisposable())
    }

    private final class Wrapper: Disposable {
        var isDisposed: Bool
        let disposable: ViewModelOwnerDisposable

        init(_ disposable: ViewModelOwnerDisposable) {
            self.disposable = disposable
            isDisposed = false
        }

        func dispose() {
            disposable.dispose()
            isDisposed = true
        }
    }

    public func add(_ disposable: ViewModelOwnerDisposable) {
        inner.add(Wrapper(disposable))
    }
}
```

and then

```swift
func didSetViewModel(_ viewModel: ViewModel, disposeBag: ScopedDisposable<CompositeDisposable>) {
  disposeBag += AnyDisposable {
    print("Disposed Profile")
  }
}
```

The docs have already been updated accordingly